# Chartjs chart not loading depending on the method I use

Tags: angular, load, chart.js

I'm using Chartjs in angular to draw several charts on my page; a line chart, two bar charts, a pie chart and two doughnuts.

While coding and looking for help on the internet I've come with two methods to load/code the charts. Both methods causes me a huge problem, each one its own problem, and I can't find a solution for any of them.

Let's use a doughnut chart as an example.

The **first method** I can use to make it work:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myDonut"></canvas>
```

**Controller**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myDonut").getContext("2d");
 $scope.myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {, 
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Billed hours","Pending hours","Write off"],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ['#a2f5a6','#FFFF99','#ffb2b2'],
          data: auxDonutData
        }
      ]
    }
```

And here is the **second method** I can use

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myLine" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="lineChart.data" chart-labels="lineChart.labels" chart-colors="lineColors" chart-options="lineChart.options" chart-series="lineChart.series" ></canvas>
```

**Controller**

```
I just fill the variable lineChart with data and voilà. Really really easy.
```

WELL. Both methods "work". I mean, they draw the correct data on the correct graphs... BUT and here is what is driving me crazy:

- The **first method** NEVER loads the graph on the first load of the page. If I close the browser and reopen the page, the chart wont load. No erros thrown. It just wont show. If I F5, it loads, no problem at all and everything cool.
- The **second method** loads from the begining as it should do BUT I can't .destroy() it when I need to do it (to erase the data on it) because I don't have a variable assigned to the chart like in the first method ($scope.myDoughnutChart) where it doesn't load on first load BUT I can .destroy() the graph whenever I want.

**I need the graph to load from the begining AND being able to destroy it.**

Help, please.

**EDIT**

auxDonutData is filled with data this way:

On first load of the controller I call to a function that gets data from the database and calls to four more functions. The first one calculates some stuff and stores it in the variable *$scope.year_overview*, the other three initializes 3 graphs, a line chart, a bar chart and the donut chart, in that order.

The function that initializes the donut chart goes like this:

```
var auxDonutData = [];

      if($scope.times_fees_filter == "times")
      {
        if(timesIncomeFilter == "hours")
        {
          auxDonutData = [$scope.year_overview.times.hours.rendered.total,$scope.year_overview.times.hours.pending.total,$scope.year_overview.times.hours.write_off.total];

        }
        else
        {
          auxDonutData = [$scope.year_overview.times.income.rendered.total,$scope.year_overview.times.income.pending.total,$scope.year_overview.times.income.write_off.total];

        }
      }

var ctx = document.getElementById("myDonut").getContext("2d");
 $scope.myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {, 
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Billed hours","Pending hours","Write off"],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ['#a2f5a6','#FFFF99','#ffb2b2'],
          data: auxDonutData
        }
      ]
    }
```

So, as you can see, I just fill in first the variable auxDonutData and then I create the graph

**EDIT**

I have discovered that, on the first approach, if I inmediately .destroy() the variable $scope.myDoughnutChart it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined".

So... It is not being initialized? That's why the graph doesn't show on first load?

Comment: Can you add the code to show how you populate `auxDonutData`?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post